# optimization of static function referenced once

Tags: c, optimization, embedded, inline, iar

I am writing embedded code for MSP430, using the IAR compiler at the highest optimization level (speed or size does not change anything).

I define a function as static, then reference it only once, in the same file.
Since the function has internal linkage, and is used exactly once, I expected the optimizer to perform inline expansion. I can see no reason not to.

The function is short, it results in 16 words of machine code. It is called from an ISR.
Adding the inline keyword makes the function inline, but the optimizer seems to need the hint. Having it inline saves two `push`/`pop`s to the stack, one `calla` and one `reta`.

Am I right to expect inline expansion to be performed (even without the `inline` keyword), or am I missing something?

---

**Edit:** a few more tests showed that the inline expansion was dependent on the size of the function, and that the threshold was quite low. It seems to be around 15 or 16 words of machine code. Above that and the optimizer does not expand if not given the keyword.

I still don't see why it wouldn't (readability shouldn't be the concern of an optimizer, should it?), but I understand that IAR only can answer this.

Comment: I would expect it, too. But it is compiler-dependent. AFAIK, nothing dictates what optimizations compilers must perform for different optimization levels. Maybe peruse the docs for your compiler and see if such information is present.

Comment: The compiler doc says that the optimizer performs inline expansion in the highest optimization level. Actually, the IDE lets the user check/uncheck inline expansion. I am not sure if it only refers to inlining when given the hint, or if it includes inlining when not given the hint.

Comment: Also make sure you have no form of debugging enabled, or the compiler will likely be very reluctant to inline anything.

Comment: @Lundin: interesting suggestion. The only option I could find was C/C++ compiler -> Output -> Generate debug information. Unfortunately, no luck.

Comment: GCC would definitely inline in this situation.

Comment: Regarding the edit about size being a factor - the optimizer might be overly concerned about code size but not have the smarts to figure out that there's only a single call instance (so size wouldn't be an issue). If that's what's going on, then clearly IAR can make an improvement here.  Given the call sequence you describe, it looks like with a 16 word function and 2 call sites you'd get about the same code size for inlining vs. not.  With 3+ call sites, inlining would increase code size.

Comment: @Michael Burr: there is indeed only one call to the function, and since it has internal linkage it cannot be called from outside the compilation unit. If there were two calls the code would be larger if inlined (twice 16 words, versus 16 + 2 `calla` + 2 `reta` + 2 `push`es + 2 `pop`s). I got a nice and humble answer from IAR: heuristics are a complex matter and no optimizer can be perfect. Giving as many hints as possible is the best the programmer can do. On the other hand on average, it is best not trying to outsmart the compiler by writing overly "clever" code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using an IAR ARM compiler version that's a few years old (v5.2); how much of this might apply to the MSP430 compiler I have no idea.

The IAR ARM compiler inlines static functions that aren't explicitly marked `inline` for me using any of the 'high' optimization settings, `-Oh` (balanced), `-Ohs` (speed), or `-Ohz` (size) - including static functions with some measure of complexity (loops for example).

Of course, I imagine that there are some static functions which aren't inlined, but a quick check indicates that the IAR compiler is performing this optimization in general.

So, I'd expect the compiler to inline your static function - but if you want to depend on these optimization, I think you'd need to examine the output (as you did). Of course, what optimizations and how they're applied are completely compiler dependent, so only IAR can really answer the question of whether the optimization 'should' occur (or defend why they might decide that it shouldn't). You might want to talk with IAR if you think they aren't performing this optimization appropriately.  They might be able to give you a pointer as to why it's not happening in this particular case.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. In short, there is no apparent reason not to inline, and I could let IAR defend their optimizer by writing to them. Strange that it is working for ARM and not for MSP430.

Comment: @Gauthier:  I would not wast your time writing to them (it will probably take more of your time that this trivial optimisation will ever save).  The behaviour of thier compiler breaks no rules so there is nothing to defend and a solution is provided.  If you want it inlined then you must explicitly direct it; that is IMO prefereable in any case since it is more deterministic.  It is also quite possible that thier optimser heuristics overall yields better results than GCC.  You are sweating the small stuff.

Comment: @Clifford: Good point. I did take the time to ask the question here and on the TI forum, but it was in order to have the opportunity to understand something I might have missed. This specific case is as you said trivial, it's the learning experience that motivated me. I did drop a quick mail to IAR support though, we'll see if that leads to something.

Comment: My experience with IAR support has been good. However, for something like this, I'd guess you'll probably get a "non-answer" answer, like "thank you for the report, we'll look into it..." (since it's technically not a bug). But it might make them take some notice, particularly if this isn't the only report.

Comment: apparently IAR is considering adding a compiler flag to make the inlining decisions more aggressive than they are today. This was my first experience with IAR support, and I must say I am very impressed by the answer I got.

Comment: The aggressive inlining flag is now implemented and accessible from the IDE, and does exactly what I asked for.

Comment: @Gauthier: it took a while, but it's great that they responded with the feature you wanted.

Comment: @Michael, I think it went rather fast :) The feature has been available for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is not required to inline code (even if explicitly marked `inline`), and optimisers vary in sophistication and strategy. So this is really a question for your compiler vendor (consulting the documentation may also help).

If the function is particularly large, the compiler may have made the decision that the avoidance of a function call overhead was insignificant in the overall scheme.

Your compiler may have a `_force_inline` keyword or similar, which would be regarded and a directive rather than a suggestion (as `inline` typically is on most compilers).

One possible argument for not in-lining, is to maintain deterministic performance under maintenance.  If a later second reference caused it to no longer be in-lined, your code execution speed may change in ways that would be detrimental to your application's performance requirements, while remaining in-lined might significantly impact code size.

**[edit]** Reading the [documentation](ftp://ftp.iar.se/WWWfiles/msp430/guides/EW430_CompilerReference.pdf), on your compiler the directive `#pragma inline=forced` is required immediately before the function definition, otherwise in-lining is dependent upon the optimisers heuristics.  Even when forced, in-lining will not occur at low or no optimisation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While inlining is really what I want, I already know how to force it. As stated in my question, even the hint is enough for the optimizer to kick in. The question was if I was missing a fair reason for the optimizer not to inline. Apparently (since gcc would inline in this situation), there is no evident reason not to inline.

Answer (score 0):

According to an IAR employee in this thread [IAR Size optimization & inline functions](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/groups/msp430/show/30953.php):

> Officially, it's only supported if the compiler sees the definition in a
>   header file or in the same source file.
>   However, as an experiment we've tried out something called "multifile
>   compilation", where you can feed several C files to the compiler at the
>   same time, allowing it to inline between compilation units. Note that
>   this is purely experimental, and the IDE has no support for it.
>
> ...
>
> Personally, should I write an application today, I would not use the
>   --mfc option. Instead I would place the function I would like to inline
>   in header files, must like you do when you write C++ class definitions
>   with inlined methods.

Comment: The reply you link to is from 2007. Multifile compilation is now released and accessible from the IDE. Note that my question was about a function defined in the same source file (as quoted). The function is even `static`, so may not be used in other modules. The forum thread you link to is about inlining across modules.

Comment: @Gauthier: Weird.  I read that as "Since the function has *no* internal linkage" and assumed it was the same thing I was doing.